# Getting Windows 7 to be server and MacBook Pro Lion to be client

Tags: synergy

When using any version of Synergy on both my MacBook Pro that has Lion 64-bit installed and my Windows 7 64-bit machine, I can't get it to work.

I want Windows 7 to be the main host (the server) and my MacBook to be the client. On the Windows 7 machine, it just says: **"Synergy 1.4.6:  Waiting for clients"** in the taskbar. (*Don't pay too much attention to the version number...its doing this for all versions.*) It just simply won't work.

However if I turn around and make my MacBook the server and my Windows 7 system the client, it works absolutely fine! Why does it work one way, but not the other? I'm really confused how to fix this and I really want my PC to control my Mac, not my Mac to control my PC.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have the setup you describe -- Windows 7 server and Lion client -- and am able to get it to work (save for some minor bugs already noted elsewhere by others).  Have you verified you've opened up the Firewall appropriately?  When first running the app I was prompted to add it to my Firewall (I technically have it so that it can listen on any port).